# Align the content in the nav bar to the position center in bootsrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, icons

I tried a lot but i,but unable to fix the content in the center of the navigation bar.
but can able to fix that in left or right. the following is the code i used.

```
<h4 class="navbar-text navbar-center">Mytitle </h4>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this -> **[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6uCVU/)**

First you have to remove the generic classes of bootstrap.

We do that by resetting the `float:none` option !

Then we center the content using `text-align:center`.

CSS:

```
#example .navbar .nav,
#example .navbar .nav > li
{
    float:none; /*To remove the inbuilt float option*/
    display:inline-block;
}

#example .navbar-inner {
    text-align:center;/*To center this*/
}

.navbar .brand{
    float:none; /*To remove the inbuilt float option*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/yHprm/220/ something like this but... depends if you have something else there... it will help somemore code.

```
.parentDiv {text-align: center}
```

Comment: its not working :( i m using the frame work "bootstrap"

Comment: there is no .navbar-center in bootstrap, so you'll have to add you style to this class.

Comment: add this to you css .navbar-center {text-align: center} or .navbar-center { margin: 0 auto; display: inline-block;}

Comment: is there any further option is available instead of changing CSS

Comment: if you need more help, I need more from your HTML code.

Comment: i fixed the problem by just removing the "navbar-text" if i use this i cant able to locate the text in center. instead of this can use own class to color the text

Answer (score 0):

Please try it

```
.navbar-text {
    width: 92%;  /* new edit */
    text-align: center;  /* new edit */
}
```